# Check IIS website existence and copy items to physical path

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I need to check whether if a Site exists in IIS. If exits, then I need to execute PS script if not then I need to create a new IIS website of that name and execute the PS script.

I have scribbled something here but caused few errors.

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
Function WAPublish
{
Param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]
    $RELEASEDIR,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]
    $DESTINATION,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]
    $SERVER,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [String]
    $SITE
    )
if(Test-Path IIS:\Sites\$site)
    {
        Write-Host "The provided website name is $site and it is a valid website`r`n" -ForegroundColor Cyan
        Get-ChildItem "$RELEASEDIR\*"
        Copy-Item "$RELEASEDIR\*" "\\$SERVER\$DESTINATION" -Force -Recurse
        Write-Host "Deployment completed"
        invoke-command -computername "$SERVER" -scriptblock {iisreset /RESTART}
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "There is not a website present in the name provided`r`n" -ForegroundColor Red
        New-Website –Name $SITE –PhysicalPath "$DESTINATION"
        if ($error) { exit 1 }
        Get-ChildItem "$RELEASEDIR\*"
        Copy-Item "$RELEASEDIR\*" "\\$SERVER\$DESTINATION" -Force -Recurse
        Write-Host "Deployment completed"
        invoke-command -computername "$SERVER" -scriptblock {iisreset /RESTART}
        Exit
    }
if ($error) { exit 1 }
}

WAPublish -RELEASEDIR "C:\Location" -DESTINATION "c$\test" -SERVER "server" -SITE "test"
```

Error

```
New-Website : Parameter 'PhysicalPath' should point to existing path.
At C:\Release\RPCPS\WebApiPublish-2.ps1:29 char:9
+         New-Website –Name $SITE –PhysicalPath "$DESTINATION"
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-Website], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Provider.NewWebsiteCommand
```

Answer (score 2):

Physical path should be an existing folder. It can't create a new folder, when a new site is created. I would modify your code to create a folder if it doesn't exist,

```
Write-Host "There is not a website present in the name provided`r`n" -ForegroundColor Red
# Create Folder if it doesn't exist 
if(!(Test-Path -Path $DESTINATION -PathType Container)) 
{ 
    New-Item -Path $DESTINATION -ItemType Directory 
} 
New-Website –Name $SITE –PhysicalPath "$DESTINATION"
```

Comment: I am still getting same error.

New-Website : Parameter 'PhysicalPath' should point to existing path.
At C:\Release\RPCPS\test.ps1:34 char:13
+             New-Website –Name $SITE –PhysicalPath "$DESTINATION"
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-Website], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Provider.NewWebsiteCommand

Comment: What is the value of $DESTINATION ?